# Power Shell script to Send email using Office 365 SMTP with attachment

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have this code to send email with attachment:-

```
$encpassword = convertto-securestring -String "*****" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "***@***", $encpassword
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $sourceWebURL -Credentials $cred
Send-MailMessage -to "" -from "" -Credentials $cred -bcc "" -Port "587" -UseSSL "true" -Subject "subject" -Body "<b>1</b><br><b>2</b>" -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com"  -Attachments "C:\s.csv"
```

but based on the documentation's warning that `Send-MailMessage` is obsolete @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.3

and at the same time using `Send-PnPMail` does not support sending attachments @  https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Send-PnPMail.html .

so my question is how we can send an email using power shell using a supported/recommended approach which allow us to attach a file.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered sending a link to a file rather than an attachment? There are a number of benefits of using a link to a file stored in SharePoint, rather than attaching a file to each email.

Comment: @CallumCrowley the requirement is to keep the functionality as-is,, so the customer need to get an attachment rather than link to a document on sharepoint/one-drive

Comment: is there a solution you have got to this problem because I am having a similar one? It would be of great help to me.

Answer (score -1):

We can send the files as attachment, while sending the mail from PowerShell. This is done by adding an extra parameter -Attachment’ to the Send-MailMessage command. In addition to the mail body, we can specify the file location of the attachment file, which has to be sent along with the mail. In the code block given below, we are using Gmail relay Server to relay the mail, which contains the file located at the local machine. This attachment location is specified directly in the ‘Send-MailMessage’ command, using the ‘Attachment’ parameter.

Attachment Sending code is given below.

```
$Body = "Sample Email Body"
$SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
$SmtpUser = 'kspriyaranjan@gmail.com'
$smtpPassword = '<Input Gmail Account Password Here>'
$MailtTo = 'priyaranjan.ks@hotmail.com'
$MailFrom = 'kspriyaranjan@gmail.com'
$MailSubject = "Testing Mail Attachments using $SmtpServer"
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $SmtpUser, $($smtpPassword |
ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
Send-MailMessage -To "$MailtTo" -from "$MailFrom" -Subject $MailSubject -Body "$Body" -Attachments "C:\PS\SampleAttachment.txt" -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -BodyAsHtml -UseSsl -Credential $Credentials
write-Output "Custom Message : Attachment Email Sent to Business Users"
```

For more information, please refer to:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37782.powershell-send-mails-with-attachments-using-office-365-and-gmail-smtp-server.aspx

Comment: seems you did not read my question, i already know about Send-MailMessage but it is obsolete